# magento2 how to add js show/hide for company field in shipping form in checkout?

Tags: jquery, magento2

I have a added a select field `type` via layout Processor in checkout shipping address form. On change of this field I need to display/hide `company` field.

Can anyone suggest where I can add this part of js/jQuery code?

I tried putting in \Magento_Checkout\templates\onepage.phtml which is not working in production.

Any suggestions/code examples are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can do the work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('select[name=type]').on('change', function() {
  $('input[name=company]').toggle();
});
</script>
```